# How do I use wget/curl to download from a site I am logged into?

Tags: bash, wget

Some parts of wikipedia appear differently when you're logged in.  I would like to wget user pages so they would appear as if I was logged in.

Is there a way I can wget user pages like this

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:A
```

this is the login page:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Login&campaign=ACP3
```

Comment: Related: [How to download this webpage with Wget?](https://superuser.com/q/214846/87805) & [Using wget to download images in facebook conversations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137772/21471)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21919431/1136018 for an easy solution using Google Chrome + cURL

Answer (score 68, accepted):

#### The easy way: login with your browser, and give the cookies to `wget`

Easiest method: in general, you need to provide `wget` or `curl` with the (logged-in) cookies from a particular website for them to fetch pages *as if you were logged in*.

If you are using Firefox, it's easy to do via the [*cookie.txt*](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-txt) add-on. Install the add-on, and:

1. Click on the plugin and save the `cookies.txt` file (you can change the filename/destination).
2. Open up a terminal, and use `wget` with the `--load-cookies=FILENAME` option, e.g.

   ```
    wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:A
   ```

- For *curl*, it's `curl --cookie cookies.txt ...`

(I will try to update this answer for Chrome/Chromium users)

#### The hard way: use *curl* (preferably) or `wget` to manage the entire session

- A detailed how-to is beyond the scope of this answer, but you use *curl* with the `--cookie-jar` or *wget* with the `--save-cookies --keep-session-cookies`options, along with the HTTP/S PUT method to log in to a site, save the login cookies, and then use them to simulate a browser.
- Needless to say, this requires going through the HTML source for the login page (get input field names, etc.), and is often difficult to get to work for sites using anything beyond simple login/password authentication.
- **Tip:** if you go this route, it is often much simpler to deal with the *mobile* version of a website (if available), at least for the authentication step.

Comment: Nice tip. The code for the mobile site is often way cleaner.

Comment: how does such a cookies.txt look like?

Comment: This "Export Cookies" add-on created a cookies file with the cookies for every single site I've accessed in Firefox.  So if you follow this answer you'll be presenting all of your cookies to whatever site you are hitting.  I consider this a security flaw in this answer.  You can easily work around this problem by using:  `grep mydomain cookies.txt > mydomain-cookies.txt`

Comment: For chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg

Comment: You can use [Cookie Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/a-cookie-manager/) add-on in Firefox to export only selected cookies.

Answer (score 26):

Another easy solution that worked for me without installing anything extra:

- Open "Network" tab of ["Web Developer"](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) tool: Ctrl-Shift-E
- Visit the page you want to save (e.g. a photo behind a login)
- Right click the request and choose ['Copy'->'Copy as cURL'](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#copy)

This will give you a command that you can paste directly into your shell, that has all your cookie credentials e.g.

```
curl 'https://mysite.test/my-secure-dir/picture1.jpg' \ 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...' \
-H 'Cookie: SESSIONID=abcdef1234567890'
```

You can then modify the URL in the command to fetch whatever you want.

This feature is present both in Chrome and Firefox developer tools.

Comment: This is a fantastic tip!

Answer (score 4):

With cURL is really easy to handle cookies in both ways.

`curl www.target-url.com -c cookie.txt` then will save a file named cookie.txt. But you need to log in, so need to use --data with arguments like: `curl -X --data "var1=1&var2=2" www.target-url.com/login.php -c cookie.txt`.
Once you get loggued cookie you can send it with: 
`curl www.target-url.com/?user-page.php -b cookie.txt`

Just use -c (--cookie) or -b (--cookie-jar) to save and send.

Note1: Using cURL CLI is a lot of easier than PHP and maybe faster ;)

For save the final content you can easily add `> filename.html` to your cURL command then save full html code.

Note2 about "full": Yo cannot render javascript with cURL, just get the source code.

Comment: `-X` parameter stands for "do post", but using `--data=xxx` `-X` is implicit, so you can remove it surely.

Comment: `-b` is `read cookie`

Answer (score 3):

For those still interested in this questions, there's a very useful Chrome extension called **CurlWGet** that allows you to generate a `wget` / `curl` request with authentication measures, etc. with one click. To install this extension, follow the steps below:

1. Install the extension from the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/curlwget/jmocjfidanebdlinpbcdkcmgdifblncg).
2. Go the web page that would you like to download.
3. Start the download.
4. The extension will generate a link for you.

Enjoy!

Comment: And that extension was recognized to contain malware, sadly :(

Answer (score 3):

have a look at [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/cliget/) for Firefox.

When you're about to download, on the final download dialog you get the option to copy the download as curl command line to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

The blog post [Wget with Firefox Cookies](http://surniaulula.com/2012/10/11/wget-with-firefox-cookies/) shows how to access the sqlite data file in which Firefox stores its cookies. That way one doesn't need to manually export the cookies for use with wget. A comment suggests that it doesn't work with session cookies, but it worked fine for the sites I tried it with.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
wget --user=username --password=password http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:A
```

Comment: yes - unfortunately that didn't work =(

Comment: Note: this syntax works for basic HTTP authentication only (where your browser pops up a special Username/Password dialog box), not for webpage-based authentication.

Comment: basic HTTP authentication url format is admin:admin@www.url.com but as @izx has say, basic HTTP is browser feature, not PHP programming nor code.

If someday you need to access an htaccess protected url you can use that mode ;D

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not a good way to authenticate: if you, by accident make such scripts public, people can use your password.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? May not be a catch all answer but still an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data 'user=goyamy&passwrd=mypassword' http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/
```

See also this link:

[How to download this webpage with wget?](https://superuser.com/questions/214846/how-to-download-this-webpage-with-wget)

Comment: Just like any output. Use `> filename.html` to save the output at current dir or put a complete filepath. This applies both Linux and Windows systems.

Comment: So, im seeing that wget has many features like cURL, or viceversa. It can do POST, so it can do login to websites. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For more complicated website based logins you should also consider to use a Python script and some module which imitates a browser, like http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/ instead of `curl` or `wget`.

This way session cookies are handled automatically, you can follow links and fill login forms, and so "script" yourself through the login process as if using your web browser.

Comment: Yeah, using mechanize can be really nice. Also (and originally) available in Perl, if that is more your cup of tea.