# How do I bypass the license page to download Oracle/Sun Java on a server with wget?

Tags: command-line, java, oracle, wget

I'm trying to install Liferay on Ubuntu Server 12.04, which requires JRE and recommends version 6.

I can't find JRE6 in an authoritative repository, and I can't work out how to get past the licence agreement for a manual (wget) download.

Can I add a value to wget to accept the Oracle licence agreement and download the file?

Thanks

Comment: For future searchers, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959815/2184122

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### "Automated" Oracle Java Downloads (JRE/JDK 6/7 and others...)

> You will need *sqlite3* installed; it's a tiny package, use `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` if you need to.

1. Open Firefox, go to the Java downloads page for the version/variant you need, and click on the *Accept License Agreement* radio button.

   - For example, here's the [Java 6 SE download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-downloads-1637591.html):

   [image]
2. Open a terminal, and paste this to extract the necessary Oracle session cookies from the Firefox SQLite cookie database into a `cookies` format text file `wget` can use ([source for script](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/using-the-cookies-sqlite-from-firefox-3-in-wget-653227/#post4289989)):

   ```
   echo ".mode tabs
   select host, case when host glob '.*' then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end, path,
   case when isSecure then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end, expiry, name, value
   from moz_cookies;" | sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite
   | grep -i oracle > /tmp/oracle-cookies.txt
   ```
3. Now use `wget` to download with those session cookies:

   ```
   wget --load-cookies=/tmp/oracle-cookies.txt wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u14-b08/jdk-6u14-linux-x64.bin
   ```
4. **Notes:**

   - You can use these cookies for *any* Oracle download as long as it comes from the `otn-pub` directory
   - You can paste the script in to a .sh file for easier use
   - The cookies are not associated with IP, so for a headless/CLI server, simply SCP or transfer the `cookies` file and you can download from any computer (but there is a 30-minute timeout on the cookie, so beware)
   - *Related:* [How do I use wget/curl to download from a site I am logged into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161778/how-do-i-use-wget-curl-to-download-from-a-site-i-am-logged-into/)

Comment: Is it 100% legal?

Comment: @tachyons Yes, you do have to open a browser *on some computer* and click on "Accept License Agreement" before you can do any of this...

Comment: Cool trick, but any idea if it still works?  I keep trying it but it only downloads an html page content that says "Sorry! In order to download products from the OTN you must agree to the OTN license terms".  Either I'm doing it wrong or Oracle got wise to this...

Comment: You can always just past that url into the browser as well :)

Comment: While this answer is great, the one I just posted below is *much* easier.  Of course, you may need to fall back to this one if mine stops working.

Answer (score 6):

There is a similar question on stackoverflow: [How to automate download and instalation of Java JDK on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-instalation-of-java-jdk-on-linux)

The answer using wget is:

```
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

The last argument is the url to download from. Different java version archives differ not only in version, but extension too.

Comment: No longer works.

Comment: yeah this doesn't work, keeps redirecting me to login.oracle.com

Answer (score 6):

A tip from [mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-oracle-jdk-8-on-centos/): you can use `wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" [link from download page]` to download without needing to extract cookies from your browser.

Comment: This is clearly better than the other answers as long as it works. It is still the case at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to izx answer, there is a [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookietxt-export/lopabhfecdfhgogdbojmaicoicjekelh?hl=en) you can use to export your cookies, so you do not have to use sqlite.

Comment: @izx's answer is great. But I much prefer pushy's suggestion of using "Cookie.txt export" to get the cookie contents (corresponding to step 2 of izx's answer) rather than using sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way with out cookies:

- Start the download in your browser
- Pause the download
- Copy the url being used for the download
- Use the url with wget:
  `wget --no-check-certificate URL_FOR_DOWNLOAD`

The URL is probably only valid for a limited amount of time (often 30minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just get the content given by the chrome extension mentioned by pushy in a file on your linux. Then copy the dl adresse from oracle page and add it to your wget command. For example, to dl Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1.0):

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/download$ wget -x --load-cookies cookies.txt http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/R2/linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip`