# How can I download from 4shared.com via terminal?

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use wget/curl to download from a site I am logged into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161778/how-do-i-use-wget-curl-to-download-from-a-site-i-am-logged-into)

I want to ask if I can download from 4shared.om via terminal?
I tried to use

```
wget http://dc379.4shared.com/download/cm3oo7bA/Applied_radiological_Anatomy.pdf?tsid=20120817-033302-fa3ef03c
```

and

```
wget --max-redirect=1000 http://dc379.4shared.com/download/cm3oo7bA/Applied_radiological_Anatomy.pdf?tsid=20120817-033302-fa3ef03c
```

and

```
curl http://dc379.4shared.com/download/cm3oo7bA/Applied_radiological_Anatomy.pdf?tsid=20120817-033302-fa3ef03c
```

but none of them do the task. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Well,I just downloaded it.

In your first command you used

```
wget http://dc379.4shared.com/download/cm3oo7bA/Applied_radiological_Anatomy.pdf?tsid=20120817-033302-fa3ef03c
```

instead of that use only upto the .pdf extension. That is

```
wget http://dc379.4shared.com/download/cm3oo7bA/Applied_radiological_Anatomy.pdf
```

Comment: I opened the file,but its not working.

Comment: it tried the command but it didn't work as 4shared needs login and some cookies. so the file you downloaded was just html page.
I followed the this steps and it works:

1 - I installed Export cookies plugin in firefox 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/

2 - i open the file page on 4shared and choose "download" then "free download" then copied the link as in this screenshot
http://i.imgur.com/du6vt.jpg

3 - i saved the cookies to cookies.txt and use the following command
wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://{the link i copied}

it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't download directly from 4shared. 4shared does not allow to download directly.
You can download directly if you have premium account but cannot download from terminal.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can get a link that will work for several minutes. when i past it in a browser it will work. i can get as shown in the following screenshot

http://i.imgur.com/du6vt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [nitstorm](https://askubuntu.com/users/18887/nitstorm):

I followed these steps and it works:

1. I installed [Export cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/) plugin in Firefox.
2. I open the file page on 4shared and choose "download" then "free download" then copied the link as in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o0yJ.jpg).
3. I saved the cookies to cookies.txt and use the following command

   ```
   wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://{the link i copied}
   ```

It works.