# wget how to download file from a web page that prompts you to click on "Agree" condition

Tags: downloads, wget

I'd like to download a file using the wget utility. I followed the instruction on "[How do I use wget/curl to download from a site I am logged into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161778/how-do-i-use-wget-curl-to-download-from-a-site-i-am-logged-into)" and the download process works; however, the saved cookies expires after a certain time, so I'm unable to continue downloading the file the following day.

Here's the URL I'm trying to download the a file from:

https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt

The download page requires that I click the "Agree" button before I can proceed with the download.

Is there a way to include the "Agree" submission with the wget utility?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit a form using `wget`, using the `--post-data` option. First, look at the form that page uses:

```
<form name="acceptedForm" id="acceptedForm" action="submitAgreement" method="post">
...
        <button id="agree_terms_use" name="agreementValue" type="submit" value="Agree">Agree</button>  &nbsp; 
        <button id="disagree_terms_use" name="agreementValue" type="submit" value="Do Not Agree">Do Not Agree</button>
```

Typically, the value of the `action` attribute is used to get the target URL, which becomes  `https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement`. The `name`s of the form elements become the parameters. Then you need to save the cookies that you get from accepting the agreement. From [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432161/2072269), we can construct the command needed:

```
wget --post-data="agreementValue=Agree" https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement --save-cookies cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --delete-after
```

Then, we can use these cookies to download the file:

```
wget --load-cookies=cookie.txt 'https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt?AgreementSessionObject=Agree'
```

Comment: +1 And is this also possible with aria2c? ;)

Comment: @A.B. I don't think aria2c has command line options to submit POST data. That will have to be done by `wget` or `curl`. Once that is done, you can use the cookie file with `aria2c`.

Comment: Thank you Muru!  The steps you provided answered my question.