# How to download a file from a website that prompts a popup form?

Tags: command-line, scripts, downloads, wget

For the last couple of years we have been able to download a `FedACH` file from Federal Reserve website (frbservices.org) using the `wget` utility.  The link below provided the original solution:

[wget how to download file from a web page that prompts you to click on "Agree" condition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615142/wget-how-to-download-file-from-a-web-page-that-prompts-you-to-click-on-agree-c)

1. get the cookies:

   ```
   wget --post-data="agreementValue=Agree" https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement --save-cookies cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --delete-after
   ```
2. download the file:

   ```
   wget --load-cookies=cookie.txt 'https://frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt?AgreementSessionObject=Agree'
   ```

Using this `wget` commands just downloads `https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/download.html` because the website is requesting that a popup form be filled in after clicking the “Agree” button now. Is there some way to just close the form using `wget`?

In IE and Chrome, the steps below were executed to download the desired file:

1. Go to URL: https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt
2. Click Agree button.
3. Form is displayed requesting organization information.
4. Click Close button on form (I did not fill in any information).
5. Go to URL: https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt
6. File downloads successfully.

Answer (score 6):

The website requires you to have two cookies set: A valid `JSESSIONID` and the `abaDataCaptureCookie` called agreement cookie. The first can be obtained with your first `wget` command, the second one needs to be added manually.

1. Obtain a valid `JSESSIONID` and save it to `cookies.txt`:

   ```
   wget --post-data="agreementValue=Agree" frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --delete-after
   ```
2. Add the `abaDataCaptureCookie` line:

   ```
   echo -e "frbservices.org\tFALSE\t/EPaymentsDirectory/\tFALSE\t0\tabaDataCaptureCookie\tabaDataCaptureCookie" >>cookies.txt
   ```
3. Download the file:

   ```
   wget --load-cookies cookies.txt frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt
   ```

I'm not quite sure how long the first cookie stays valid, but I assume you won't download the list multiple times per hour, so obtaining a new one on every run seems OK to me – that's the failsafe approach after all.

Script version of the above steps, using a tempfile as the cookie file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cookiefile=$(mktemp)
wget --post-data="agreementValue=Agree" frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement --save-cookies $cookiefile --keep-session-cookies --delete-after
echo -e "frbservices.org\tFALSE\t/EPaymentsDirectory/\tFALSE\t0\tabaDataCaptureCookie\tabaDataCaptureCookie" >>$cookiefile
wget --load-cookies $cookiefile frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt
```

Running this script will save the current `FedACHdir.txt` to the current directory without leaving a `cookies.txt` lying around, if there's already a file with this name `wget` adds a number and saves it as e.g. `FedACHdir.txt.1`.

On resolving this issue I found great help here: [Format of cookies when using wget? · U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36531/format-of-cookies-when-using-wget)

Comment: Almost forgot how much fun it is to solve things like that.

Comment: Thanks Dessert.  The steps you provided answered my question.

Comment: @GMP If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.